# Setting permissions for /var/www/html on ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, permissions, sftp

How do you set permissions for the ubuntu user and apache user on an amazon ec2 instance on the var/www folder.

What happens now is that if I own the folder by ubuntu user then the apache user is not permitted to create files and if I own using apache folder I am not able to write files using SFTP.

I want to achieve both these tasks and still have correct permissions.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add the `ubuntu` user to the same group as Apache. On Ubuntu the user and group Apache runs under is `www-data`. So here's the command to add the user `ubuntu` to the `www-data` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me. I restarted apache after running this. But still the same issue is there.

Comment: What are the permissions on that directory?

Comment: Please check this.
`drwxrwsr-x 12 www-data www-data 4096 Oct  1 16:13 html`